# Using data from array list in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I´m learning to use apis and i have this array from an api

```
{
"candidate_id":1244,
 "candidate_name": "ABRAHAM",
 "vData": [
        {
            "document_name": "Identificación",
            "document_status": 0,
            "kind_document": 1,
            "document_route": "",
            "required": false
        },
        {
            "document_name": "Comprobante de domicilio",
            "document_status": 0,
            "kind_document": 2,
            "document_route": "",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "document_name": "Estado de cuenta",
            "document_status": 0,
            "kind_document": 3,
            "document_route": "",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "document_name": "Doc. Datos Personares",
            "document_status": 0,
            "kind_document": 25,
            "document_route": "",
            "required": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I can acces to the array this way  `console.log('lista: ', arrPayroll.archivo);`
but I dont know how to spilt an use the content of it
I need to make something like

```
setvDocNameIdentificacion(vData.document_name);
setvKindDocument1(vData.kind_document);
```

where i want  that vData.document_name is "Identificacion" and vData.kind_document is 1

//////////EDIT///////
what I need is a way to use the data inside of vData array to make some validations, so i need to put every elemnt of the arrays on diferent variables

for example since the first object on vData is

```
"document_name": "Identificación",
"document_status": 0,
"kind_document": 1,
"document_route": "",
"required": false
```

i need to use the elements to do something like this

```
setvDocumentName("Identificación")
setvDocumentstatus(0)
setvKindDocument(1),
setvDocument_route("")
setvRequired(false)
```

so i can use them for making views like

```
{vKindDocument == 1 ? 
<Text style={styles.PaymentText}>El documento es {vDocumentName} </Text>
:
<Text style={styles.PaymentText}>No hay documento</Text>
}
```

any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Could you be more clear? Below answers are what you are looking for or not? If not, could you add a comment on answer explaining what do you want?

Comment: i edited the post, im trying to be more clear, the answers dont worked for me

Comment: I saw and thanks for that. I'm trying to answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find at first the element in the array and then create 5 state variables in which store all the informations you need to render your `Text`. Something like:

```
const [vDocumentName, setvDocumentName] = useState("");
const [vDocumentstatus, setvDocumentstatus] = useState(-1);
const [vKindDocument, setvKindDocument] = useState(-1);
const [vDocument_route, setvDocument_route] =useState("");
const [vRequired, setvRequired] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
   // retrieve data from api...
   let elementINeedToRender = arrPayroll.archivo.vData.find(x => x.document_name === "Identificación" && x.kind_document === 1);
   setvDocumentName(elementINeedToRender.document_name);
   setvDocumentstatus(elementINeedToRender.document_status);
   setvKindDocument(elementINeedToRender.kind_document);
   setvDocument_route(elementINeedToRender.document_route);
   setvRequired(elementINeedToRender.required);
}, []);

...

{vKindDocument == 1 ? 
<Text style={styles.PaymentText}>El documento es {vDocumentName} </Text>
:
<Text style={styles.PaymentText}>No hay documento</Text>
}
```

Now your view shows `<Text style={styles.PaymentText}>El documento es Identificación </Text>`

Comment: @user10625391 no problem man, have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 0):

Question you asked was not clear enough but I assume you wanna find all the objects where the document_name is "Identificacion" and kind_document is 1.

You can use [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and it returns an array:

```js
let response = {
"candidate_id":1244,
 "candidate_name": "ABRAHAM",
 "vData": [
        {
            "document_name": "Identificación",
            "document_status": 0,
            "kind_document": 1,
            "document_route": "",
            "required": false
        },
        {
            "document_name": "Comprobante de domicilio",
            "document_status": 0,
            "kind_document": 2,
            "document_route": "",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "document_name": "Estado de cuenta",
            "document_status": 0,
            "kind_document": 3,
            "document_route": "",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "document_name": "Doc. Datos Personares",
            "document_status": 0,
            "kind_document": 25,
            "document_route": "",
            "required": false
        }
    ]
};

console.log(response.vData.filter(el => (el["document_name"] === "Identificación" && el["kind_document"] === 1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .find of js array this:

```
const found = {You object}?.vData?.find(lookFor => {
  if (condition) {
    return 1;
  }
  return -1;
})

if (found) {
  /* your code like setvDocNameIdentificacion(found?.document_name); */
}
```